# Javascript change event kills click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This occurs when I bind a change event to a textarea and then a clickevent to a button. If I'm focused in the textarea and have made a change and then click on the button, only the change event fires. An example is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0t1pzh7/12/)

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea').change(function() {
        alert('mefirst')
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea name="details" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
```

If you unbind the textarea the click event will work as expected. Any suggestions would be helpful (happens in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: If you change it to console.log instead of alert, does it work?

Comment: It doesn't work because you have the alert, if you change the change event to something else it will continue and fire the click. See http://jsfiddle.net/p0t1pzh7/15/

Comment: onchange occurs when the element loses focus.

Comment: As you can see, it works with console.log: http://jsfiddle.net/ypxzvumk/

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Must be a different issue I'm having in my app. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the alerts, both the change and click event is firing but the browser doesn't know what to do with 2 alerts. If the alert() is changed to console.log(), both events are logged.

```
 $('textarea').change(function() {
    console.log('changed')
});
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    console.log('submitted');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0t1pzh7/13/